# Simulating a joint distribution with the inverse method

Tags: simulation, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I have the following joint distribution:

$$f(x, y) = 3x^2y^xe^{-x^3}(1 + x),\quad x \gt 0,\ y  \in (0,1).$$

I want to simulate a sample of this distribution through the inverse method but I don't know if my procedure is right.

### What I've tried

In order to simulate the random variable above I'll have to compute the inverse marginal cdf for $x, y$ , $F^{-1}_X(x), F^{-1}_Y(x)$ and then for $U, V \sim U_{[0, 1]}$ I'll be able to simulate the random variable. But I don't know how to compute the marginal cdf's in this case. Any hints or advice are more than welcome!

Comment: Hint: you will likely have to integrate out either $x$ or $y$ to find a marginal distribution.  Which one leads to a (much) easier integral?  Here's another hint: $$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(-e^{-x^3}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}y^{1+x}\right).$$

Comment: Once again, @whuber, you've helped me! When i find one of the marginal distribuitions I'll be able to find the other one because $f_Y(y | x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$. And then, with both marginals I can get both CDF's, and I'll just have to invert then in order to properly simulate this r.v, right?

Comment: You can't generate from the two marginals to get a value from the joint; the variables are not independent. Instead you use the general decomposition into marginal and conditional ... $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) . f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

Comment: Note also that a naïve implementation of the inverse cdf method in dimensions larger than one does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record, integrating out $y$ gives the marginal density

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y = 3x^2e^{-x^3}.$$

By inspection (or integration *via* a substitution for $x^3$) this has distribution function

$$F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-x^3}\quad (x \ge 0).$$

Conditional on $x,$ the density of $y$ is proportional to $y^x,$ whose distribution function is

$$F_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = y^{1+x}\quad (0\le y \le 1).$$

Thus, if we draw a uniform variable $U$ in the range $[0,1],$ $x = F_X^{-1}(U)$ will have the same distribution as $X;$ and then if we independently draw another uniform variable $V,$ solving the equation

$$V = F_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$$

for $y$ will give us one realization $(x,y)$ from the distribution with density $f.$

A practical example is this `R` implementation, which draws `n` *iid* values from this distribution:

```R
rjoint <- function(n) {
  x <- (-log(runif(n)))^(1/3)
  y <- runif(n)^(1/(1+x))
  cbind(x, y)
}
```

(It saves a little time by applying $F_X^{-1}$ to $1-U,$ which also has a uniform distribution.)

The return value is an $n\times 2$ array with $x$ in the first column and $y$ in the second.

The result of drawing ten million values with `x <- rjoint(1e7)` (which takes two seconds on this machine) looks like this figure, where contours of the resulting 2D density are drawn over a colored contour plot of $f$ (both use the same contour intervals ranging from $0.2$ near the bottom to $2.2$ at the top).

[image: Figure]

The agreement looks good.

---

#### Comment

This problem had two obvious approaches: integrate out $y$ or integrate out $x.$  Both work, but the latter is so nasty I don't know how to do it by hand. The Wolfram Language 13 engine found an expression:

[image: Figure 2]

However, it doesn't know how to simplify or invert this function ;-).

Comment: I just got a free dev' license this year for the Wolfram Language. I should use it more, especially for problems where Wolfram alpha times out. Anyway, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) gives some elementary definitions for the Airy-related functions in the Wolfram language output.